# How to add SSH key to github from Linux console?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I am working on Linux console environment without GUI. I want to work with github.

After generating ssh key, I can see a very very long string from id_rsa.pub file. A serious problem for me: how to add this long string to github.com Account Settings/SSH keys ?

I don't want to type letters one by one from my Windows.

Comment: Are you using something like PuTTY to connect between the two?

Comment: @Leigh I have a Linux environment on Virtualbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can add it using the GitHub API.

```
curl -u "USERNAME:PASSWORD" --data "{\"title\": \"TITLE\", \"key\": \"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}" https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

You'll need to replace:

- USERNAME with your github's username
- PASSWORD with your github's password
- TITLE with the title you want for your key to be stored
- "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" with yours ssh-key path (if different)

For more information, read: https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1) Use GitHub's API to [create the public key](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#create-a-public-key) on your account.

2) Use another computer with a GUI to ssh into that Linux machine, grab the key, and use GitHub's website to add the public key to your account.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily copy it out by SSHing into the Linux machine from the Windows side with PuTTY.

Once you're in:

1. Show the contents of the file with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or whatever the path to your key is.
2. Select the key from the output in PuTTY by highlighting it with your mouse; this automatically loads it into your clipboard.
3. Log in to Github and then paste in the key through their website.